# Rolling active users that were also active in previous days in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, window-functions

I would like to calculate the rolling number of active users that were also active x or more times in the previous y days. For simplicity lets say >3 times in 5 days

The data I have is of the form

```
|    date   | user_id   |
------------------
|2019-01-01 | user1     |
|2019-01-01 | user2     |
|2019-01-01 | user1     |
|2019-01-02 | user1     |
|2019-01-02 | user3     |
|2019-01-02 | user4     |
|2019-01-03 | user2     |
|2019-01-03 | user3     |
```

I have tried to use aggregate functions to group user_id by date and the having a window function sum the users that exist >3 times in the 5 preceding rows. 
Aggregate the users by date is fine using:

```
SELECT date, ARRAY_AGG(distinct user_id) as users
FROM `table` 
WHERE date > DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
GROUP BY date
```

Returning an array structure like this.

```
|    date   | users     |
------------------
|2019-01-01 | user1     |
|           | user2     |
|2019-01-02 | user1     |
|           | user3     |
|           | user4     |
|2019-01-03 | user2     |
|           | user3     |
```

But here I'm stuck. Can I do something like this? But what analytical function should I use?

```
WITH activity as (
  SELECT date, ARRAY_AGG(distinct user_id) as users
  FROM `table` 
  WHERE date > DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
  GROUP BY date
)

SELECT date, xxxx OVER (PARTITION BY date ORDER BY date ROWS 5 PRECEDING) as returning_users
FROM activity
```

The output that I would like is:

```
|    date   | returning_users  |
------------------
|2019-01-01 | 123              |
|2019-01-02 | 1234             |
|2019-01-03 | 12345            |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may well be right that there are some suitable window functions to achieve this, but I am not familiar with them if there are.

However since there is no existing solution, here is a working method just using joins:

```
WITH ACTIVE_DAYS AS (
  SELECT
    a.date,
    a.user_id,
    COUNT(DISTINCT b.date) AS ActiveDays
  FROM
    DATA a
  JOIN
    DATA b
  ON
    a.user_id = b.user_id
    AND b.date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(a.date, INTERVAL 5 DAY) AND DATE_SUB(a.date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
  GROUP BY
    1,
    2)
SELECT
  a.date,
  COUNT(DISTINCT a.user_id) AS DAU,
  COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN b.ActiveDays >= 3 THEN a.user_id END)) AS DAU_Meet_Criteria
FROM
  DATA a
LEFT JOIN
  ACTIVE_DAYS b
ON
  a.date = b.date
  AND a.user_id = b.user_id
GROUP BY
  1
ORDER BY
  1
```

By editing the `date_sub` functions and the case statement in the second `count(distinct...` statement you could achieve some alternative logic.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot. Then I will stop chasing the analytical function and go with the join approach instead.